# Android/Java Verify Large File Too Slow

Tags: android, signature, verify

I currently have a process in an Android app that checks a few ZIP files against a signature file using a signed certificate much like what is demoed here (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/security/apisign/vstep4.html)

However, since my files are all 200MB - 900MB it takes anywhere from 11-25 minutes to go through all the files and verify. We are currently using "SHA1withRSA" and are wanting to upgrade to use "SHA256withRSA". But, that takes even longer since it is a more enhanced encryption. The iOS counterpart to this app does the verification of the same ZIP files in around 2 minutes, so I am wondering how I can speed this process up? Changing the buffer size or reworking the While loop did not yield any results.

I was wondering if there is a way to just verify a portion of the zip instead of looping through the whole file.

```
public boolean verify(String dataFile, String signFile) throws Exception {
    byte[] sign = readSignature(signFile);
    Signature sg = Signature.getInstance("SHA1withRSA", "BC");
    sg.initVerify(publicKey);

    FileInputStream datafis = new FileInputStream(dataFile);
    BufferedInputStream bufin = new BufferedInputStream(datafis);

    byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];

    int len;       

    while (bufin.available() !=0) {
        len = bufin.read(buffer);
        sg.update(buffer, 0, len);
    }

    bufin.close();
    return sg.verify(sign);
```

Comment: I haven't benchmarked them, but have you considered using SpongyCastle instead of BouncyCastle? https://github.com/rtyley/spongycastle